# What is the difference between the below processes?

Tags: c#, winforms, process

This process is running "independently" from my app. I can use my form meanwhile the script is running, not waiting for exit.

```
string strCmdText = "some command line script";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

This one though stops the process in my form till command line window is being closed:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
p.StartInfo.FileName = cmd.exe;
p.Start();
```

To me both seems to be the same `process.start()`. So what is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are very similar but **not** equivalent.

Here is how [`Process.Start` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs#a4d69c6ed7ca3aed);

```
public static Process Start(string fileName, string arguments)
{
     return Start(new ProcessStartInfo(fileName, arguments));
}
```

[`new ProcessStartInfo(fileName, arguments)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5zzxthe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor sets second parameter to arguments string which is [`ProcessStartInfo.Arguments` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5zzxthe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) not [`Verb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.verb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. And also;

```
public static Process Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
{
     Process process = new Process();
     if (startInfo == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("startInfo");
     process.StartInfo = startInfo;
     if (process.Start()) {
         return process;
     }
     return null;
}
```

As you can see from it's documentation;

> The overload associates the resource with a new `Process` component. If
>   the process is already running, no additional process is started.
>   Instead, the existing process resource is reused and no new `Process`
>   component is created. In such a case, instead of returning a new
>   `Process` component, `Start` returns `null` to the calling procedure.